# Cannot connect to remote MongoDB from EMR cluster with spark-shell

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I'm trying to connect to a remote Mongo database from a EMR cluster. The following code is executed with the command `spark-shell --packages com.stratio.datasource:spark-mongodb_2.10:0.11.2`:

```
import com.stratio.datasource.mongodb._
import com.stratio.datasource.mongodb.config._
import com.stratio.datasource.mongodb.config.MongodbConfig._

val builder = MongodbConfigBuilder(Map(Host -> List("[IP.OF.REMOTE.HOST]:3001"), Database -> "meteor", Collection ->"my_target_collection", ("user", "user_name"), ("database", "meteor"), ("password", "my_password")))
val readConfig = builder.build()
val mongoRDD = sqlContext.fromMongoDB(readConfig)
```

Spark-shell responds with the following error:

```
16/07/26 15:44:35 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: aggregate at MongodbSchema.scala:47
16/07/26 15:44:45 WARN DAGScheduler: Creating new stage failed due to exception - job: 1
com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=Unknown, servers=[{address=[IP.OF.REMOTE.HOST]:3001, type=Unknown, state=Connecting, exception={java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: response too long: 1347703880}}]
    at com.mongodb.BaseCluster.getDescription(BaseCluster.java:128)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.getClusterDescription(DBTCPConnector.java:394)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.getType(DBTCPConnector.java:571)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.getReplicaSetStatus(DBTCPConnector.java:362)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.getReplicaSetStatus(Mongo.java:446)
.
.
.
```

After reading for a while, a few responses here in SO and other forums state that the `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: response too long: 1347703880` error might be caused by a faulty Mongo driver. Based on that I started executing spark-shell with updated drivers like so:

```
spark-shell --packages com.stratio.datasource:spark-mongodb_2.10:0.11.2 --jars casbah-commons_2.10-3.1.1.jar,casbah-core_2.10-3.1.1.jar,casbah-query_2.10-3.1.1ja.jar,mongo-java-driver-2.13.0.jar
```

Of course before this I downloaded the jars and stored them in the same route as the spark-shell was executed. Nonetheless, with this approach spark-shell answers with the following cryptic error message:

```
Exception in thread "dag-scheduler-event-loop" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/casbah/query/dsl/CurrentDateOp
    at com.mongodb.casbah.MongoClient.apply(MongoClient.scala:218)
    at com.stratio.datasource.mongodb.partitioner.MongodbPartitioner.isShardedCollection(MongodbPartitioner.scala:78)
```

It is worth mentioning that the target MongoDB is a Meteor Mongo database, that's why I'm trying to connect with `[IP.OF.REMOTE.HOST]:3001` instead of using the port `27017`.

What might be the issue? I've followed many tutorials but all of them seem to have the MongoDB in the same host, allowing them to declare `localhost:27017` in the credentials. Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using MongoDB's official Java driver instead. This was my first experience with Spark and the Scala programming language, so I wasn't very familiar with the idea of using plain Java JARs yet.

### The solution

I downloaded the necessary JARs and stored them in the same directory as the job file, which is a Scala file. So the directory looked something like:

```
/job_directory
|--job.scala
|--bson-3.0.1.jar
|--mongodb-driver-3.0.1.jar
|--mongodb-driver-core-3.0.1.jar
```

Then, I start spark-shell as follows to load the JARs and its classes into the shell environment:

```
spark-shell --jars "mongodb-driver-3.0.1.jar,mongodb-driver-core-3.0.1.jar,bson-3.0.1.jar"
```

Next, I execute the following to load the source code of the job into the spark-shell:

```
:load job.scala
```

Finally I execute the main object in my job like so:

```
MainObject.main(Array())
```

As of the code inside the MainObject, it is merely as the [tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/java/client/) states:

```
val mongo = new MongoClient(IP_OF_REMOTE_MONGO , 27017)
val db = mongo.getDB(DB_NAME)
```

Hopefully this will help future readers and spark-shell/Scala beginners!

Comment: Here are the download links for the JARs I talked about: [bson.jar](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/bson/3.0.1/bson-3.0.1.jar) , [mongodb-driver.jar](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver/3.0.1/mongodb-driver-3.0.1.jar) and [mongodb-driver-core.jar](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver-core/3.0.1/mongodb-driver-core-3.0.1.jar)