# Read From mongoDB in Scala

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, sbt

I want to create a standalone scala code that uses a custom setting to read from MongoDB using [this code](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/scala/read-from-mongodb/) in MongoDB website.

When I run SBT package, I face some errors. I guess it is related to wrong creation method of SparkSession. Can you please give me a hint to fix it?

My `Buid.sbt` content

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.mongodb.spark" %% "mongo-spark-connector" % "2.4.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.1"
)
```

`Firstapp.scala` code

```
package com.mongodb
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import com.mongodb.spark.config.{ReadConfig,WriteConfig}
import com.mongodb.spark.MongoSpark
import org.bson.Document

object FirstApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val sc = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local")
    .appName("MongoSparkConnectorIntro")
    .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.myCollection")
    .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.myCollection")
    .getOrCreate()

    val readConfig = ReadConfig(Map("collection" -> "spark", "readPreference.name" -> "secondaryPreferred"), Some(ReadConfig(sc)))
    val customRdd = MongoSpark.load(sc, readConfig)

    println(customRdd.count)
    println(customRdd.first.toJson)

 }
}
```

and the error after running `sbt package`

```
    value toJson is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Row
[error]     println(customRdd.first.toJson)
[error]                             ^
[error] one error found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 10 s, completed Jun 10, 2020 6:10:50 PM
```

---

EDIT1:

I tried the solution but it does not compile properly. The `Buid.sbt` content is the same as above. I changed `SimpleApp.scala` into:

```
import com.mongodb.spark.MongoSpark
import com.mongodb.spark.config.ReadConfig
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object FirstApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
        .master("local")
        .appName("MongoSparkConnectorIntro")
        .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.myCollection")
        .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.myCollection")
        .getOrCreate()
    val sc = spark.sparkContext

    val readConfig = ReadConfig(Map("collection" -> "spark", "readPreference.name" -> "secondaryPreferred"), Some(ReadConfig(sc)))
    val customRdd = MongoSpark.load(sc)
    println(customRdd.count())
    println(customRdd.first.toJson)

 }
}
```

The compilation result:

```
$ spark-submit   --class "FirstApp"   --master local[4]   target/scala-2.11/root-2_2.11-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 
20/06/12 07:09:53 WARN Utils: Your hostname, Project resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 10.0.2.15 instead (on interface enp0s3)
20/06/12 07:09:53 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
20/06/12 07:09:54 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
20/06/12 07:09:54 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.4.5
20/06/12 07:09:54 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: MongoSparkConnectorIntro
20/06/12 07:09:55 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: sadegh
20/06/12 07:09:55 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: sadegh
20/06/12 07:09:55 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
20/06/12 07:09:55 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
20/06/12 07:09:55 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(sadegh); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(sadegh); groups with modify permissions: Set()
20/06/12 07:09:55 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 33031.
20/06/12 07:09:55 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
20/06/12 07:09:55 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
20/06/12 07:09:55 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
20/06/12 07:09:55 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
20/06/12 07:09:55 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-7405e1be-08e8-4f58-b88e-b8f01f8fe87e
20/06/12 07:09:55 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 366.3 MB
20/06/12 07:09:55 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
20/06/12 07:09:55 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
20/06/12 07:09:55 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4041.
20/06/12 07:09:56 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://10.0.2.15:4041
20/06/12 07:09:56 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/Folder/target/scala-2.11/root-2_2.11-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar at spark://10.0.2.15:33031/jars/root-2_2.11-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar with timestamp 1591938596069
20/06/12 07:09:56 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
20/06/12 07:09:56 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 42815.
20/06/12 07:09:56 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 10.0.2.15:42815
20/06/12 07:09:56 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
20/06/12 07:09:56 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 10.0.2.15, 42815, None)
20/06/12 07:09:56 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 10.0.2.15:42815 with 366.3 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 10.0.2.15, 42815, None)
20/06/12 07:09:56 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 10.0.2.15, 42815, None)
20/06/12 07:09:56 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 10.0.2.15, 42815, None)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/spark/config/ReadConfig$
    at FirstApp$.main(SimpleApp.scala:16)
    at FirstApp.main(SimpleApp.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:845)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:184)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:920)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:929)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.spark.config.ReadConfig$
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 14 more
20/06/12 07:09:56 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
20/06/12 07:09:56 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.0.2.15:4041
20/06/12 07:09:56 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
20/06/12 07:09:56 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
20/06/12 07:09:56 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
20/06/12 07:09:56 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
20/06/12 07:09:56 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
20/06/12 07:09:56 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
20/06/12 07:09:56 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
20/06/12 07:09:56 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-7f90ac08-403c-4a3f-bb45-ea24a347c380
20/06/12 07:09:56 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-78cb32aa-c6d1-4ba4-b94f-16d3761d181b
```

---

EDIT2:

I added `.config("spark.jars.packages", "org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.4.1")` to `SimpleApp.scala` but the error remains the same as EDIT1 section:

```
import com.mongodb.spark.MongoSpark
import com.mongodb.spark.config.ReadConfig
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object FirstApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
        .master("local")
        .appName("MongoSparkConnectorIntro")
        .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.myCollection")
        .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.myCollection")
        .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.4.1")
        .getOrCreate()
    val sc = spark.sparkContext

    val readConfig = ReadConfig(Map("collection" -> "spark", "readPreference.name" -> "secondaryPreferred"), Some(ReadConfig(sc)))
    val customRdd = MongoSpark.load(sc)
    println(customRdd.count())
    println(customRdd.first.toJson)

 }
}
```

Comment: Uhm, with the code as it is I do not see anything wrong with it, it should work according to the docs. Sadly I am not really versed on Spark and less in this module, hope someone else can help you. - Maybe there are some implicits on this package `com.mongodb.spark._` which add such **extension method**, try replacing `import com.mongodb.spark.MongoSpark` with `import com.mongodb.spark._` and see it that fixes the error.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. unfortunately, it always ends in the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the detail steps to create a Scala Project to read the data from MongoDB with Apache spark

You can create a project with IDE or manually with the following files included

1. *SparkMongo/project/plugins.sbt*
2. *SparkMongo/src/main/scala/com/test/FirstMongoSparkApp.scala*
3. *SparkMongo/build.sbt*

**project/plugins.sbt**

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.10")
```

**build.sbt**

```
name := "SparkMongo"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

val sparkVersion = "2.4.1"
val mongoSparkVersion = "2.4.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.mongodb.spark" %% "mongo-spark-connector" %  mongoSparkVersion ,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion
)

assemblyJarName in assembly := s"${name.value}_${scalaBinaryVersion.value}-${version.value}.jar"

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

**SparkMongo/src/main/scala/com/test/FirstMongoSparkApp.scala**

```
package com.test

import com.mongodb.spark.MongoSpark
import com.mongodb.spark.config.ReadConfig
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object FirstMongoSparkApp extends App {

  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local")
    .appName("MongoSparkProject")
    .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://localhost/test.cities")
    .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://localhost/test.outputCities")
    .getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  val readConfig = ReadConfig(Map("collection" -> "cities", "readPreference.name" -> "secondaryPreferred"), Some(ReadConfig(spark.sparkContext)))
  val customRdd = MongoSpark.load(spark.sparkContext, readConfig)

  customRdd.toDF().show(false)

}
```

Now you can perform `sbt assembly` will generate a jar file `SparkMongo_2.11-0.1.jar`

You can run the jar file as

```
spark-submit --class "com.test.FirstMongoSparkApp" --master "local" target/scala-2.11/SparkMongo_2.11-0.1.jar
```

To run without issues make sure you have the same version of spark as in the dependency, In this case **2.4.1** and mongoDB version **2.6+**

Comment: Did this help you?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is you are trying to use `SparkSession` as `SparkContext` but they are not the same thing. If you replace `sc` to `SparkContext` everything will compile.

```
import com.mongodb.spark.MongoSpark
import com.mongodb.spark.config.ReadConfig
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local")
    .appName("MongoSparkConnectorIntro")
    .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.myCollection")
    .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.myCollection")
    .getOrCreate()
val sc = spark.sparkContext

val readConfig = ReadConfig(Map("collection" -> "spark", "readPreference.name" -> "secondaryPreferred"), Some(ReadConfig(sc)))
val customRdd = MongoSpark.load(sc)
println(customRdd.count())
println(customRdd.first.toJson)
```

Comment: thank you very much! You are correct about my mistake. I guess there is still something missing in my code, can you take a look? I already updated the question

Comment: @Woeitg is common problem in spark applications. Maybe this line in config should help: `.config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.4.1')` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45142629/cant-connect-to-mongo-db-via-spark

Comment: I add the above line but the error remains the same. See the EDIT2 part in the question

Comment: This problem can be caused by many reasons, take a look at these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42646510/where-can-i-find-the-jars-folder-in-spark-1-6
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52385123/pyspark-mongodb-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-mongodb-client-model-coll

Comment: The first thing I would looking for: Does library `mongo-spark-connector` jar is at the `$SPARK_HOME/jars` or not?

Comment: There are lots of jars files there, but nothing that contain the word "mongo"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215827/discussion-between-boris-azanov-and-woeitg).

Comment: I copied the mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.4.1.jar into my $SPARK_HOME/jars folder but the errors remain the same

Comment: this is more the one possible solution, just try something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38595098/cannot-connect-to-remote-mongodb-from-emr-cluster-with-spark-shell

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you were able to solve your issue, but this is how it worked for me. You need to provide `--packages` at the `spark-submit` as follows:

```
spark-submit --class "FirstApp" --master local[4] --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.4.1  target/scala-2.11/root-2_2.11-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```